# Grails test-app: How can I disable junitreport?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit

I am trying to run some unit tests for my grails app, via "grails test-app -unit". This works as expected.

However, when the tests are done, junitreport takes way too long to generate the HTML results, eg:

[junitreport] Transform time: 33294ms

33 seconds (on top of the rest of the time) is ridiculous when I want to rapidly make modifications and re-test. Is there a way I can disable this, and just use the plain-text output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can do:

```
grails test-app -no-reports
```

It looks like this causes none of the reports to be generated, I'm not sure if that works for you or not.

Also available is a `-xml` argument. Perhaps its transformation will be quicker; you might give it a try.

I found this out by digging through `$GRAILS_HOME/scripts/TestApp.groovy` - if you dig through it you might find something better that works for you.

Comment: I took a look - after a bit of fiddling, I discovered that -no-reports still outputs the plain-text reports - perfect! Thanks!

Comment: +1 great tip, I didn't know you could turn off html reports, and I never look at them